# Bootstrap Modal Sectioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I need help with setting up my bootstrap modal to show something like this: 
This is Facebook's so trying to make it look similar.

[image]

I already have the video set up but having hard time trying to get the comments sections to be in the right place. My buttons are on the bottom. Here's my code. It won't exactly do what I need it to. Tried hundreds of diff ways. Either, I am stupid or haven't found the right way yet. I tried to do it with `col-*-*` as well.

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-wide">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Challenge Video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <video id="compVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup="{}" height="200" width="300"><source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a div that contains the comments, but if you want the comments to line up on the x-axis with the video you can wrap both in a `div` that has the CSS rule `display: flexbox` applied to it. Or you can add the CSS rule `display: inline` to the comment div. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1489/)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like this**

**css**

```
.modal-body
{
  display:table;
}
video,.comments
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**html**

```
 <div id="videoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-wide">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Challenge Video</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" >


            <video id="compVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup="{}" height="200" width="300"><source src="test1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        <div class="comments">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam adipisci in asperiores repellendus aperiam pariatur quidem deserunt provident nam beatae, porro, illo dolore iure, voluptate veniam cupiditate aspernatur esse modi?
            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Open Modal</button>
```